# SMS with Uno in 2022

Tags: arduino-uno, sms

I'm trying to develop a simple sensor-triggered SMS message to mobile service from an Uno as a learning project in North America.
I initially thought that it might be wise to purchase a GSM/3G compatible board and follow a tutorial such as this one: https://docs.arduino.cc/tutorials/mkr-gsm-1400/gsm-send-sms or go with Arduino's IoT SIM card package: https://store-usa.arduino.cc/products/arduino-sim-mkr-gsm-1400-cellular-kit (though this one is not exactly what I want since its SIM card only works with Arduino's IoT Cloud service and is not direct SMS to mobile capable).

However, after a bit of further research, it seems as though 2G (GSM)/3G networks are effectively phased out (by this year) and so I'm concerned that the above options won't work.  I'm also generally confused as to the best low-cost SIM cards for those options above (my service will be sending only tens of messages per month).  I have to yet to find similarly well supported shields/boards/SIM cards for 4G/5G networks in North America in the Arduino community.

Can anyone recommend a solution or point out where I may be incorrect in my analysis of current options?

I've considered postponing this particular project and instead accomplishing the same task with WiFi and IFTTT...

If not evident already: I'm new to working with SMS and IoT.

Comment: Unless you *need* SMS I wouldn't bother with it. Or at best use WiFi and an online SMS gateway service. If you need remote connectivity then a 4G WiFi hotspot will connect you to the internet.

Comment: Have you tried searching for terms like "Arduino LTE board"? A quick search seams promising. Though it is definitely easier to build when you use wifi and - if necessary - a standard wifi hotspot.

Comment: @chrisl Yes and I concluded that the Botletics SIM7000A Shield (along with a Hologram SIM card) is the likely the best way to go for 4g support on Arduino based on these resources: https://www.instructables.com/LTE-NB-IoT-Shield-for-Arduino/ and https://github.com/botletics/SIM7000-LTE-Shield.  Do you agree?

Comment: Looks good to me

Comment: any luck on getting SMS to work with the hologram sim and SIM7000?

Comment: @trevor haven't gotten around to it yet.  I decided for the time being to just use a wifi board